# How to get custom painted component to change according to new data?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, java-2d

I'm developing an application/game in a Java GUI with netbeans 8.0. In this game you have a very simple U.I. that is a map (GIF image) of the Italian peninsula inside a label, a start button and few labels for the debug.

In this game you have all the coordinates(lat and lon) of the Italian biggest cities, and when someone clicks the start button a city will be extracted randomly, so the name of the city will appear in a label and the user has to guess the position of that city. Now I solved all the castings between geographical coordinates and pixels, and I have the data model working correctly so you don't have to worry about all that stuff.

When the user clicks on the map to guess the position of the city I wanted to mark the correct position of the city with a red dot, and here there are all my problems... I'll post some code to be clearer ;)

```
    private void lbMappaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    //gets the pixels coordinates of the user click                             
    mouseX = evt.getX();
    mouseY = evt.getY();
    //casting datas for coordinates
    double cLon = 12.565006;
    double cLat = 42.094436;
    double w = 6.626604;
    double e = 18.520248;
    double n = 47.091932;
    double s = 36.646879;
    double kLat = 0.97;
    double kLon = 1;
    //earth radius
    double R = 6371;
    //formula to convert the coordinates of the click to geographical lon,
    double mouseLon = cLon + (mouseX - dimX / 2) * (e - cLon) / kLon / dimX * 2;
    //formula to convert the coordinates of the click to geo lat
    double mouseLat = cLat + (mouseY - dimY / 2) * (s - cLat) / kLat / dimY * 2;

    //this is the formula to find the pixel coordinates of the extracted city
    comuneX = (int) (((longitudine - cLon) / (e - cLon) / kLon / dimX * 2) + dimX / 2);
    comuneY = (int) (((latitudine - cLat) / (s - cLat) / kLat / dimY * 2) + dimY / 2);


    //EVERY TIME I CALCULATE THIS STUFF ABOVE I WANTED TO DRAW A RED DOT/OVAL ON THE MAP


    double lonA = Math.toRadians(mouseLon);
    double latA = Math.toRadians(mouseLat);
    double lonB = Math.toRadians(longitudine);
    double latB = Math.toRadians(latitudine);

    double distanza = R * Math.acos(Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB) + Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonA - lonB));

    lonA = Math.toRadians(e);
    latA = Math.toRadians(n);
    lonB = Math.toRadians(w);
    latB = Math.toRadians(s);
    //distance between the correct position of the city and the user click
    double distanzaMax = R * Math.acos(Math.sin(latA) * Math.sin(latB) + Math.cos(latA) * Math.cos(latB) * Math.cos(lonA - lonB));
    lbDistanza.setText(Double.toString(distanza));
}
```

My class extends JFrame, and i tried to override the paint method but i discovered that it works only the first time the program renders the map.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(comuneX, comuneY, comuneX, comuneY);
}
```

How can i call this paint method every time the user clicks a point on the map? Are there any alternatives?
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You ask the component to repaint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29

Comment: For swing components, you are supposed to override the `paintComponent()` method of the specific component you want to draw, it's not recommended to override `paint()`.

Comment: thank you @JBNizet that was what i was looking for! It was very simple thanks. But now i notice that the formula to calculate the position of the city is wrong D: back to work... ahahah

Comment: Don't override `paint`, especially of top level containers like `JFrame`, they contain a number of child components which can be painted independently of the frame (without it been notified), cause what ever you might have painted to be erased in part if not in whole.  Use something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` and do your custom painting their, then add this to your frame.  When needed, call `repaint` on the this component to request that it be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling validate() and repaint() methods on JFrame to redraw the components.

```
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

Comment: `validate` in this case is not likely to be required as it relies on the layout been invalidated in some way.  From what little I can dudce, repainting the frame would be a better choice, as the OP has overriden the `paint` method of the frame, and the content pane is a container container within the frame, so you're requesting the wrong component to be painted.  Having said, the simple fact that the OP has overriden `paint` of the frame is going to cause no end of issues so even that advice is less then helpful